# Why is a string function in sql useful?

Tags: sql, string-function

I can't for the life of me figure out what good a string function in SQL can possibly do. I realize that the queries that I'm working from in the book are purely for exercise so the questions are arbitrary, but for example:

```
select substring('San Antonio, TX', 5,3);
```

Why couldn't you get the same results to this query with a regular Select statement and a Wildcard,  and what possible good could it do to find three letters starting at the fifth letter of a string? In short: what are string functions actually GOOD for in a practical sense? Can anyone give me some examples? Thank you.

Comment: That is a lousy example.  A more realistic example would be extracting the state from the string.  That requires a more complicate expression . . . which you can work on.  Hint:  `len()` or `length()` would be helpful.

Comment: "Why couldn't you get the same results to this query with a regular Select statement and a Wildcard, " --- could you?

Comment: "what are string functions actually GOOD for in a practical sense?" --- sting functions are good for manipulating strings.

Comment: Way too broad a question.

Comment: Let's pretend (clearly for purposes of your post) that Texas decides to split into two parts, West Texas (WT) and East Texas (ET). How would you do an update, replacing *TX* with *WT*, without string manipulation functions? Not everything you do with data is a simple SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two parts to your question: what use are functions at all, and, in particular, the substring.

In general, it is important that in a database you store things in their simplest form, *and never store duplicated or dependent data*. The latter principal means that if one column is any way related to another, then the design is wrong.

For example, you should store, say the given name and the family name, but you should not store the full name as well — that can be derived. Similarly, you might store the date of birth, but not the age, since that again can be derived.

String functions are useful for deriving data from simpler strings.

In particular, the `substring` function is used toe *extract* part of a string. If you have a string which is complex, it may be necessary to break it up into smaller components. This is especially useful for things like product codes or some types of serial codes which are really made up of sections.

`substring` is *not* directly useful for strings which contain varying parts. If they do, then you will need to combine them with something more complex.

Having said that, in a well-designed database there is little real need for the `substring` function. If the data is really a combination of parts, then it should already have been broken into separate columns. This the principle of **atomicity**, ensuring that each item of data is the smallest unit.

In your example, the string should have been in 2 separate columns, for town and state, so there is no further need to extract anything from it.

Comment: I'd dispute *little real need*. It's often the case that you need to manipulate strings, particularly when dealing with data received from an outside source or via manual data entry. You, like the OP, seem to forget that more happens with data than simple SELECT statements.

Comment: @KenWhite I’ve forgotten nothing. If a database is well designed, then it is atomic, and if a database is truly atomic, then there’s not much to break down. If the data has been entered wrongly, then of course it needs all the string functions you can throw at it. I didn’t say that string functions are of little use. I’m trying to explain that `substring` won’t get much of a workout if the data is atomic.

Comment: That's not what you said at all. You said *there is little real need for the substring function*, which is simply wrong. We live in the real world. Not all data is under your full control when it comes from external sources (EDI, or  for instance). Unless you live in your own little data bubble, there's a valid and real reason for string manipulation functions.

Comment: @KenWhite Fine …